# Bigcommerce Stencil Handlebars helper 'inArray'

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I'm attempting to use the Bigcommerce Handlebars helper 'inArray'.  I interpreted the helper as being able to find a particular value in an array. I can get my else statement to work but it shouldn't be outputting anything since the value I'm looking for does exist.

From the docs:

> {{inArray}}
>    Block helper that renders the block if an array has the given value. Optionally, you can specify an inverse block to render when the array does not have the given value.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - array {Array}
> - value {any}
> - options {Object}
> - returns {String}

My sample json:

```
"custom_fields": [
      {
        "id": "41005235",
        "name": "room",
        "value": "Kitchen"
      },
      {
        "id": "41005236",
        "name": "REQUIRED (NOT INCLUDED)",
        "value": "1 LED 13 WATT BULBS"
      },
      {
        "id": "41005237",
        "name": "FINISH",
        "value": "BRONZE W/POLISHED BRASS ACCENTS"
      }]
```

My Handlebars:

```
{{#inArray custom_fields "FINISH"}}
<h1>it's there</h1>
{{else}}
<h1>it's not there</h1>
{{/inArray}}
```

Comment: The inArray helper will look for the "FINISH" string, but it won't look inside the objects you have in your array. You might be better off building your own helper or using something like [this](https://axiacore.com/blog/check-if-item-array-handlebars/)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to build my own helper. From the docs: For security reasons, BigCommerce does not allow Stencil developers to define new custom Handlebars helpers – you must use the helpers currently available. However, you can suggest new custom helpers via a pull request to the Stencil Github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using {{#each}} and then an if/else statement to check for the value. For example:

```
{{#each product.custom_fields}}
    {{#if name '===' 'FINISH'}}
    <h1>It's there</h1> 
          {{else}}
    <h1>It's not there</h1>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```